# Matlab: Odd linear indexing into array with singleton dimensions

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm having trouble understanding the circumstances under which linear indexing applies.

For a 2D array, it seems intuitive:

```
>> clear x
>> x=[1 2;3 4]
x =
     1     2
     3     4
>> x([1 2])
ans =
     1     3
>> x([1;2])
ans =
     1
     3
```

For a 3D matrix, it seems intuitive:

```
>> clear y
>> y(1:2,1:2,1)=x
y =
     1     2
     3     4
>> y(1:2,1:2,2)=x+10
y(:,:,1) =
     1     2
     3     4
y(:,:,2) =
    11    12
    13    14
>> y([1 2])
ans =
     1     3
>> y([1;2])
ans =
     1
     3
```

For a 3D matrix in which the 1st two dimensions are singletons, it's not what I would expect:

```
>> clear y
>> y(1,1,1)=1
y =
     1
>> y(1,1,2)=2
y(:,:,1) =
     1
y(:,:,2) =
     2
>> y([1 2])
ans(:,:,1) =
     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     2
>> y([1;2])
ans(:,:,1) =
     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     2
```

I would have expected exactly the same as the 3D matrix without singleton dimensions.

Is there a rule that can be relied on to predict the behaviour of linear indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule for **linear indexing** of an array `x` with an array `ind` is as follows (taken from [this great post by Loren Shure](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/09/essence-of-indexing/)):

- If at least one of `x` and `ind` is not a vector (that is, if `x` or `ind` have more than one non-singleton dimension) the output has the same *shape* (*size*) as `ind`:

  ```
  >> x = rand(3,4);
  >> ind = [9 3];
  >> x(ind)
  ans =
     0.276922984960890   0.743132468124916

  >> x(ind.')
  ans =
     0.276922984960890
     0.743132468124916

  >> x = rand(2,3,4);
  >> ind = [1 2; 5 6];
  >> x(ind)
  ans =
     0.814723686393179   0.905791937075619
     0.632359246225410   0.097540404999410
  ```
- If both `x` and `ind` are vectors, the output is a vector that has the same *orientation* as `x` (i.e. the output dimension which is non-singleton is that in `x`), and the same *number of elements* as `ind`:

  ```
  >> x = 10:10:70;
  >> ind = [1 3 5];
  >> x(ind)
  ans =
       10    30    50

  >> x(ind.')
  ans =
       10    30    50

  >> x = reshape(10:10:70,1,1,[]); % 1×1×7
  >> ind = reshape([2 3 4],1,1,1,1,[]); % 1×1×1×1×3
  >> x(ind)
  ans(:,:,1) =
      20
  ans(:,:,2) =
      30
  ans(:,:,3) =
      40
  ```

---

For completeness, if **two or more indexing arrays** are applied (so this is not linear indexing anymore), the shape of the output is determined by which *dimensions* of the original array are being indexed and by the *number of elements* of each indexing array. It is independent of the shape of the indexing arrays, which are simply read in *column-major order* as usual:

```
>> x = [10 20 30 40; 50 60 70 80];
>> x(2, [1 2; 3 4])
ans =
    50    70    60    80

>> x(2, [1 2 3 4])
ans =
    50    60    70    80

>> x(2, reshape([1 2 3 4],1,1,1,[]))
ans =
    50    60    70    80
```

If there are fewer indices than the number of dimensions of `x`, the trailing dimensions of `x` are implicitly collapsed into one before the indexing is applied:

```
>> x = [10 20 30 40; 50 60 70 80];
>> x(:,:,2) = x+100;
>> x([1 2], [1; 5; 7; 8])
ans =
    10   110   130   140
    50   150   170   180
```

Comment: Another great example of inconsistencies in MATLAB based on singleton dimensions. Can't count on shape of output if you don't know for sure your input has no singleton dimensions. Same with `max` and `sum` and all those functions that work on columns except if the first dimension is singleton, then it works on rows. :(

Comment: Speaking as someone who has written multiple versions of `max` and `sum`, I feel your pain. However, all the reduction functions do support an explicit dimension argument to let you get completely programmatic behaviour.

Comment: @CrisLuengo IMO it isn't inconsistent - it works on the first non-singleton dimension, which makes a lot of sense if you consider that often you will have row or column vectors and you obviously want sum of all the elements in the case. It simply extends the same behavior to matrices - not doing that would be a pit of "gotchas".
Another thing is that max and sum both decrease final matrix dimension by 1. Operating on already singleton dimension wouldn't achieve that.

But yeah, you need to always use max(A(:)) or max(A, dim); plain old max(A) is bound to get buggy.

Comment: @ZizyArcher: I understand the reasoning, and I understand the workarounds. But it's still a cause of user errors. The true reason for these inconsistencies is that MATLAB doesn't have true vectors, there are always at least 2 dimensions. A vector and a matrix with a singleton dimension shouldn't be the same thing.

Comment: @Luis Mendo : Thanks so much.  My brain started hurting when you added the bit about nonlinear indexing, so I'll save that for another lazy Sunday in a coffee shop.  BTW, should `x = 10:10:7;` actually be `x = 10:10:70;`?